# Why does devserver give 404 response when refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So I have a React application that uses the WebPack devServer. If I am on `localhost:8080/popular` and refresh the page I get a 404 error even though I specified in my `app.js` that when we are on the `/popular` route load the `Popular` component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='container'>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/popular' component={Popular} /> //RIGHT HERE
            <Route render={function() {
              return <p>Not found</p>
            }} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding why this is happening despite researching online. When I added `historyApiFallback: true` and `publicPath: '/'` in `webpack.config.js` below it worked:

```
let path = require('path');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/' //Sets base path for our assets
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'app/index.html'
  })]
}
```

This is my `index.html` when it gets generated by Webpack:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html en="lang">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Github Battle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

My question is that why do those two properties in webpack made it work and why does it work when I load the application on `localhost:8080/` and not `localhost:8080/popular`?

Comment: Because nothing handles non `/` routes, so it's 404. With `historyApiFallback: true` express basically add one more rule `* => /`.

Comment: @dfsq So when I go on / route it will serve up my `index.html`? Since that index.html is put into the dist folder does the dev server automatically look in the dist folder by default to serve up that `index.html`?